# How to Migrating from AMQ to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am using 3 `AMQ` in my current application and decided to use now SQS in place of `AMQ` .
With `AMQ` i have been using `EC2` and micro services for produce and consume from `AMQ` .

Now when i decided to move to `SQS` in server less way,i am thinking how i can use it here ?
Here is my concern .

1. The SQS will have heavy load cumming from SNS and in server less way lambda handles that automatically but when i replace in my current application how EC2 application is going to handle that ?
2. Do i need auto scaling group here so that if heavy load in SQS then more ec2 application will come up ?
3. Is there any way i can user lambda consumer with my EC2 existing application so that my well tested EC2 application remain as it is and i would be able to use my lambda function also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SQS will have heavy load coming from SNS and in server less way
>   lambda handles that automatically but when i replace in my current
>   application how EC2 application is going to handle that ?

How is your EC2 application going to handle **what** exactly? The "load"? The SQS consumers (your EC2 instances) will poll SQS for new messages only when they are ready to consume more messages. SQS does not push messages, so it will not somehow overload your EC2 instances. SQS simply accepts messages and stores them until something asks for them (or until the messages time out).

> Do i need auto scaling group here so that if heavy load in SQS then
>   more ec2 application will come up ?

Only if you want the messages processed within a certain time frame.

> Is there any way i can use lambda consumer with my EC2 existing
>   application so that my well tested EC2 application remain as it is and
>   i would be able to use my lambda function also?

What would the Lambda function do in this scenario exactly? The only option here would be to convert your EC2 application to a Lambda application. Otherwise there is nothing extra that Lambda can do to "help" your EC2 instances process the SQS messages.

Comment: Thanks for Clarifying points here ...I am new to SQS helped a lot ..Just one clarification .If our processing is little slow and i will have huge no of messages Piles up in SQS in that case is my SQS performance will go down ? I have seen this in AMQ .

Comment: No, you never have to worry about "SQS performance". SQS is a distributed system  that can handle a virtually unlimited number of messages.